# Django get query value with manytomanyfield through

Tags: python, django

I'm new in django.
I practice how to save data into database before.
But now I don't know how to query my data out.
Please Help me.Thank you.

Here is my model: I use Manytomanyfiled through on MovieTheater.

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    title_en = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class MovieTheater(models.Model):
    movietheater = models.ManyToManyField(Movie,null=True,blank=True,through="MovieShowtime")
    movie_theater = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)     

class MovieShowtime(models.Model):
    theater = models.ForeignKey( MovieTheater, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'theater' )
    movie = models.ForeignKey( Movie, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'movie' )
    time = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

in my views.py :

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from movie.models import Movie,MovieShowtime
from django.shortcuts import render 
def index(request):
    movies = Movie.objects.all()
    times = MovieShowtime.objects.all()
    contacts = get_paginator(request, movies, 10)
    return render(request, "movie/index.html",
                  {'contacts':contacts,'movies':movies,'times':times})

def get_paginator(request, object_list, num_per_page):
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, num_per_page)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        ret = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        ret = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        ret = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return ret
```

my movie/index.html:

```
<div class="activity">
    {% for movie in contacts %}
    <div class="col-md-12  item">
    <p><h3>{{ movie.title }}</h3></p>
           {{movie.id}}
        <div class="theater">
            {% for theater in movie.movietheater_set.all %}
                {{ theater.movie_theater }}
                {{ theater.id}}
                <!--I have to filter {{movie.id}} and  {{ theater.id}} to get the time like:
                MovieShowtime.objects.filter(movie_id='9',theater_id='5')So I can get the movietime.(I don't know if it is the normal way,It's what I can think now,please guide me)
                But I don't know how to do.
                -->
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: What shows your example? `get_paginator` - is a method of class based view. Show all your imports in `views.py`

Comment: OK I edit it.It's paginator I found on internet

Comment: in your `index` view, you have `title` undefined var. What are you see in browser, when you enter url of that view?

Comment: sorry,it's ````title='hey'```` it is just for testing if index.html get the variable. It's no use anymore.I delete it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for theater in movie.movietheater_set.all %}
   {% for showtime in theater.theater.all %}
       {{ showtime.time }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's confusing because of the related names. related name is the name the oposite entity will access the one where it is defined.

If you do:

```
class MovieShowtime(models.Model):
    theater = models.ForeignKey(MovieTheater, null=True, related_name='showtimes' )
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, null=True, related_name='showtimes' )
```

Then you will access MovieShowtime like:

```
theater = MovieTheater.object.get(movie_theater='test')
for showtime in theater.showtimes.all:
  print "Movie: {} - Time: {}".format(showtime.movie.title, showtime.time)
```